# Как сделать гамбургер меню только в мобильной версии?

Tags: javascript, адаптивность

Имеется готовый код на jquery, реализующий гамбургер меню в магазине на Opencart. Но гамбургер функционирует при любом разрешении экрана, как можно ограничить его, скажем до `800px` ширины? Код:

```
$( ".cross2" ).hide();
$( ".list-group" ).hide();
$( ".hamburger2" ).click(function() {
    $( ".list-group" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        $( ".hamburger2" ).hide();
        $( ".cross2" ).show();
    });
});

$( ".cross2" ).click(function() {
    $( ".list-group" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        $( ".cross2" ).hide();
        $( ".hamburger2" ).show();
    });
});
```

Попробовал добавить if($(window).width()<800) {...}, но после этого гамбургер вообще не работает

Comment: А разметка где?

Answer (score 1):

**Я не АС в js** но может быть так ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hmenu").click(function() {
    $("nav").toggleClass("show");
    $(this).toggleClass("showw");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgrey;
  line-height: 50px;
}

ul {
  display: table;
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

ul li a {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #000;
}

@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:640px) {
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
  }
  ul,
  ul li,
  ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    color: #000;
  }
  ul li {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    display: none;
  }
  ul,
  ul li,
  ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    color: #000;
  }
  ul li {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .hmenu {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .hmenu span {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 6px auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  .hmenu.showw {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  nav.show {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<p class="hmenu">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</p>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Форум</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Портфолио</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">О разработчике</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/LenskyUser/pen/LLPrgx)

Comment: Попробую ваш код. Но чтобы было понятнее(нужно было изначально кинуть ссылку) вот мой сайт :http://yarninbobbins.com.ua/ на опенкарте

Answer (score 0):

Решение может заключаться в использовании [`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Примерно так:

```
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  #<id вашего меню> {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно не само меню скрыть, а сам гамбургер, грубо говоря, отключить. Чтобы при этом меню осталось, просто в развернутом виде.

Comment: А, ну тогда посмотрите на [другой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674145/227016), вроде он подходит.